# DateTime conversion (March 5, 2024, 5:33 a.m. to datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 5, 5, 33))

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-datetime

i have
raw date = March 5, 2024, 5:33 a.m.

is it possible to convert it in
datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 5, 5, 33)
using python

I have tried

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = "March 5, 2024, 5:33 a.m."
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p")
desired_datetime = datetime(2024, 3, 5, 5, 33)
print(desired_datetime)
```

Comment: Problem is that you have `.` between a and m. Pattern `%p` matches `AM, PM` or
`am, pm`, so without `.` in between letters.

Answer (score -2):

Your solution is almost correct. The issue in your code is in the format specifier (`%I:%M %p`). The `%I` specifier is used for hours in 12-hour format, but your input string has only a single digit for the hour, which means you should use `%I` instead of `%I` in your format string. This is the corrected version of your code.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "March 5, 2024, 5:33 a.m."
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p")
print(date_object)  # This will print: 2024-03-05 05:33:00

desired_datetime = datetime(2024, 3, 5, 5, 33)
print(desired_datetime)  # This will print: 2024-03-05 05:33:00
```

Comment: did you actually read this before posting it? "use %I instead of %I" makes no sense.